# How to filter a array element in c# mongo db driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have array in a document like this

```
 {
    "samples": [
        [
            25,
            "1535530415"
        ],
        [
            "45",
            "1535530415"
        ]
    ]
}
```

and i try to fetch the value based on second value of each array

my filter query is

```
 var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("History");
        FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filterDefintion = null ;
        ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("samples").Exclude("_id");
        filterDefintion =  Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("samples[1]","1535530415");
```

but it getting an empty array.how to filter the array values in mongo c# driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample document contains an array of arrays. To reference item at index `1` you can take advantage of the fact that in JS an array can be considered as an object where indexes are the properties, so in your case what you're storing can also be interpreted as:

```
{
    "samples": [
        {
            "0": 25,
            "1": "1535530415"
        },
        {
            "0": 45,
            "1": "1535530415"
        }
    ]
}
```

knowing that you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) to reference the right element:

```
db.History.find({ "samples": { $elemMatch: { 1: "1535530415" } } })
```

or in C# code:

```
filterDefintion = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch<BsonDocument>("samples", new BsonDocument() { { "1", "1535530415" } });
```

Comment: mickl 
is it possible to check the key (ex "0" ) is present or not?

Comment: @arunthomas sure, you can use $exists operator, like: `db.History.find({ "samples": { $elemMatch: { 1: "1535530415" } }, "samples.1": { $exists: true } })`

Comment: in C# code: 

 Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("0");